# Show that the complex measure is concentrated on the set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of the theorem in Rudin:

> Let $(X,F,\mu)$ be measure space and let $g \in L^1(\mu).$ Then we know that the function $\lambda:F\rightarrow \mathbb C$ given by 
>   $$\lambda(E)=\int_Egd\mu,$$ for all $E\in F$ is a complex measure on $F$. 
>   Now consider the set $A=\{x\in X|g(x)\neq 0\}.$ Since $g \in L^1(\mu), A$ is $\sigma$-finite, and $\lambda$ is concentrated on this set.

I understand why $A$ is $\sigma$-finite, but I can't get why $\lambda$ is concentrated on this set? The definition of concentration of measures is as follows: a measure $\lambda$ is concentrated on a set $A\in F$ provided that $\lambda(E)=\lambda(A\cap E)$ for all $E \in F.$ So we have

$$\lambda(A\cap E)=\int_{A\cap E}gd\mu=\int_{E}\chi_A gd\mu=...$$
Why is it equal $\lambda(E)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{E}gd\mu=\int_{E\cap(g=0)}gd\mu+\int_{E\cap(g\ne 0)}gd\mu=\int_{E\cap(g=0)}0d\mu+\int_{E\cap A}gd\mu=\lambda(E\cap A).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

If $B\subseteq A^c= \{x:g(x)=0\}$ then $\lambda(B)=\int_Bg=0$